# Python: Merging a string with a file

Tags: python, string, file, merge

I have a text file as such:

> 2014-12-22 10:55:19 1
>   https://stackoverflow.com/
>   Howdy, this is yet another post... this one might contain a\nline break or two
>
> 2014-12-07 12:02:49 
>   https://stackoverflow.com/
>   Hi this is my 2nd post
>
> 2014-12-02 12:18:02 
>   https://stackoverflow.com/
>   Hello this is my first post

And I want to merge it with a string which may not contain all of the previous information
String:

> 2015-01-22 17:05:52 
>   https://stackoverflow.com/
>   This is going to be my final post! Bye
>
> 2014-12-22 10:55:19 
>   https://stackoverflow.com/
>   Howdy, this is yet another post... this one might contain a\nline break or two
>
> 2014-12-07 12:02:49 
>   https://stackoverflow.com/
>   Hi this is my 2nd post

I need my text file to contain the 4 **unique** entries. My initial instinct would be to split the file by the white space and also split the string by the white space then do something like:

```
if stringEntry not in fileEntry:
    prepend stringEntry to myFile
```

I'm sure there must be a better way of doing this, if you have any ideas please give me a shout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me I would put all of the strings into a list, checking to make sure the strings are not present, before writing the final output file.

```
    #! /usr/bin/python

    f = open('files.txt')
    o = open('output.txt', 'w')
    strings = []

    for line in f:
        if line not in strings: strings.append(line)

    #I am splitting by newline, you may also be able to split by space, but depends on the string stucture.
    some_string = """line1\nline2\nline3\n"""

    elements = some_string.split('\n')
    for each in elements:
        if each not in strings:
            strings.append(each + '\n')

    for each in strings:
        o.write(each)
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I had hoped, thanks very much! Remember f.close() and o.close()